# Is is possible to loop over records in a repeat component using javascript/jquery?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, repeat

Lets say I have a table of records and a button to update multiple records in the table on a visualforce page.  I want to check the values of each record in the repeat block, and grab each records Id and checked box value and put them in a map.  I do not know how to look at each element in the repeat block when I call my function.  I am

`<script type="text/javascript">
   j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
   j$(document).ready(function() {
        function sendIds() { 
            var peopleIds = {};
            //pseudo code
            for all People p:
                peopleIds[p.Id] = p.isChecked;
        });
  );
</script>
<button onclick="sendIds();">Apply</button>
<apex:repeat value="{!Peoples}" var="People">
    <tr>
        <td><apex:outputLink value="/{!People.ID}" id="theLink">{!People.Name}</apex:outputLink></td>
        <td>{!People.Position_Description__c}</td>
        <td>{!People.Work_Email__c}</td>
        <td><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!People.CheckBox__c}" ></apex:inputCheckbox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>`

I saw some people posting on using the styleClass so then jquery and loop through and find each element with that class, but how would I get the record id then?  Thanks to all in advanced!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the record Id to the checkbox id (or other [HTML5 pass-through attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm)).

> This component supports HTML pass-through attributes using the "html-"
>   prefix. Pass-through attributes are attached to the generated 
>   tag.

So your checkbox will look something like this:

`<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!People.CheckBox__c}" styleClass="myCoolCheckbox" id="{!People.Id}" ></apex:inputCheckbox>`

or

`<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!People.CheckBox__c}" styleClass="myCoolCheckbox" html-sf-id="{!People.Id}" ></apex:inputCheckbox>`

Then in your Javascript code you can look through the checkboxes with the "myCoolCheckbox" style class applied, check which ones are selected and concatenate the Id's:

```
var selectedPeopleIds = [];
$('.myCoolCheckbox').each(function(i, obj) {
    if (obj.checked)
    {
        selectedPeopleIds.push(obj.id); // or "sf-id" attribute if it was the other scenario
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  One more question if you don't mind.

Comment: Do you use the connection.js library, or use .ajax in jquery?

Comment: I always tend to keep it simple and small, so unless you're building some really complex stuff, just use standard ajax. Avoid loading libraries in order to save a couple of lines of code ;)

Comment: Please respect the site's rules and post that as a different question. If my answer solved your original problem then accept it so that we close this thread.